# Azure log analytics Azure Synapse integration

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to bring in Azure Synapse logs into Loganalytics to create dashboards on usage level.

I have already setup in diagnostic settings to pass on the logs to my loganalytics workspace.

But while trying to execute queries from below documentation, I am getting error saying  -

Query -

//Chart the most active resource classes

> AzureDiagnostics | where Category contains "ExecRequests" | where
> Status_s == "Completed" | summarize totalQueries = dcount(RequestId_s)
> by ResourceClass_s | render barchart

Error:
**'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar expression named 'Status_s'...**

Documentation link for queries : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-monitor-workload-portal

Please let me know if there is something I am missing. I am directly logging to loganalytics workspace and running these queries inside a workbook...

Also i didnt find any proper documentation/blogs/links for connecting synapse to loganalytics, please let me know if anyone has that..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation linked in your post appears to be out of date even though the last update date is recent.

See [this link:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/azurediagnostics#resource-types)

> Azure services that use resource-specific mode store data in a table
> specific to that service and do not use the AzureDiagnostics
> table.

The link also lists a number of resource-specific tables for Synapse. "SynapseSqlPoolExecRequests" and "SynapseSqlPoolSqlRequests" are a few examples that might provide the info you're seeking.

Comment: Can we have more information streamed to loganalytics. Like queries executed in sql pool, run_time of each queries etc...?

Comment: Check out the link I provided in the above answer.  The "SynapseSQLPoolExecRequests" Log Analytics table appears to have query runtime statistics:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/synapsesqlpoolexecrequests.  (You can query "SynapseSQLPoolExecRequests" in Log Analytics.)